# Comparing a predictive model against a hypothetical model of random predictions

Tags: predictive-models

Suppose there are three apples, two oranges, and one pear in a bag.

I put my hand in a bag, and based on my tactile sense, I guessed what fruit I will grab out of the bag.

My fruit predictions are the following:

| Fruit | Prediction |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | Apple |
| Apple | Apple |
| Apple | Pear |
| Orange | Orange |
| Orange | Orange |
| Pear | Orange |

I want to show that this prediction is better than random guesses. Thus, I make the following hypothetical model:

> Knowing that there are three apples, two oranges, and one pear in the bag, randomly guess each fruit you grab.

By shuffling the list of fruits, I can make the "result" of this hypothetical model:

| Fruit | Random prediction |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | Pear |
| Apple | Apple |
| Apple | Orange |
| Orange | Orange |
| Orange | Apple |
| Pear | Apple |

Based on confusion matrix, I obtain the F1 score of the prediction of each fruit by my guesses and the random guesses.

| Fruit | My guesses | Random guesses |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 0.8 | 0.333 |
| Orange | 0.8 | 0.5 |
| Pear | NaN | NaN |

Based on this comparison, I can say that my guesses are better than random guesses at predicting apples and oranges (but not necessarily pears).

Is this comparison statistically valid?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know whether the F1-measure can be used to compare with random guessing, but there are two other performance metrics specifically designed to compare to random guessing: Cohen's Kappa and Matthew's Correlation Coefficient.

You do not explain what you mean by an "better" prediction, but let us assume that you mean that the recognition rate $p$ is better than the recognition rate of random guessing $p_c$, i.e. $p-p_c>0$.

The recognition rate is estimated as the percentage of correct guesses, and $p_c$ can be estimated as
$$\hat{p}_c = \sum_i \hat{p}_i\hat{q}_i$$
where $\hat{p}_i$ is the proportion of samples with guessed index $i$ and $\hat{q}_i$ is the proportion of samples with true index $i$.

The question is how to normalize $\hat{p}-\hat{p}_c$ so that its value is restricted to the meaningful range $[-1,1]$. This is where Cohen's Kappa and MCC differ. It is
\begin{eqnarray*}\kappa & = & \frac{\hat{p}-\hat{p}_c}{1-\hat{p}_c} \\
MCC & = & \frac{\hat{p}-\hat{p}_c}{\sqrt{\left(1-\sum_i q_i^2\right)\left(1-\sum_i p_i^2\right)}}
\end{eqnarray*}
To test whether your guessing is statistically significantly better than random guessing at the significance level $\alpha$, you must construct $(1-\alpha)$ confidence intervals for $\kappa$ or MCC and check whether it contains zero (your Null hypothesis). Approximate confidence intervals for $\kappa$ have been given by Cohen (1960) and by Fleiss, Cohen, and Everitt (1969) (see, e.g., [Reichenheim (2004)](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X0400400404) for the formulas). For MCC, I do not know of a closed formula for an approximate confidence interval, but you can use the bootstrap method to compute one, which is also a method to compute a confidence interval for $\kappa$ without relying on the asymptotic formulas.